# How to export config files in Drupal 7 with Lando

Tags: drupal, drupal-7, drush, lando

I've tried running `lando drush cex` or `lando drush config-export` but both give me this error:

> Command config-export requires Drupal core version 8+ to run.                                           [error]
>   The drush command 'cex' could not be executed.                                           [error]

Comment: The error is pretty self explanatory. the Configuration Manager module was introduced in Drupal 8.

Comment: https://docs.devwithlando.io/tutorials/drupal7.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot use `drush cex` in Drupal 7. This command was introduced in Drupal 8.

Comment: Welcome to SO. Your answer would be even better if you linked the release notes or some other resource proving your answer.